# Unable to get the closest span text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch the clicked attribute text

This is my code

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swipecontainer">
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active">
        <span>Bottle</span>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible">
        <span>Cool Drinks</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function () {
    var name = $(this).closest.find('span').text();
    alert(name);
});
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0szdyok/1/

Could you please tell me how can I get the clicked text in this case ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest is a method so needs to have `()` at the end of the call, however you don't need to use it here as `closest()` looks *up* the DOM tree, whereas you want to look *down* to find the child `span`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function () {
    var name = $(this).find('span').text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much , closest was the evil in my case :)